# How to use shoulda matchers to test a polymorphic association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shoulda, polymorphism

I'm using shoulda-matchers with rails and I'm creating a model called "comments" and another model called "post". Comments is polymorphic.

When I test with shoulda matchers in post like this

```
    it {should have_many(:comments)}
```

it get this message

> Expected Post to have a has_many
>   association called comments (Comment
>   does not have a post_id foreign key.)

In my comment model I have

```
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
```

How can I test my polymorphic association so that a post can have many comments?

p.s. the shoulda matcher documentation said it supports polymorphic associations.

Comment: What do you have on Post model?

Comment: I realise this is an old question but a solution was never posted. I asked the same question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405058) and the solution was to run my migrations in the test database (doh!).

Answer (score 10):

You shouldn't need to do anything special in your test for `should` it should just work.  On your post model ensure sure you set the `:as` option:

```
has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
```

That will ensure rails uses the proper column names `commentable_id` and `commentable_type` rather than `post_id`.