# How do I get shoulda to recognise my polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, polymorphic-associations, shoulda

An almost indentical question to this has been asked before ([How to use shoulda matchers to test a polymorphic assoication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244363)) but there was no definitive answer that helps me, so I am trying again.

I am using shoulda to test my associations and the following test fails

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe LabourEpidural do
  before {@treatment = FactoryGirl.build :treatment}
  subject {@treatment}
  it{should have_many :complications}
end
```

This fails with the following message

```
Failure/Error: it{should have_many :complications}
   Expected Treatment to have a has_many association called complications (Complication does not have a complicatable_id foreign key.)
```

The problem is that my Complication table does have a complicatable_id column. Here are the relevant parts of my models;

```
class Treatment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :complications, as: :complicatable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Complication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :complicatable, polymorphic: true
end
```

and from my schema.rb;

```
create_table "complications", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "complicatable_id"
  t.string   "complicatable_type"
end
```

As far as I can tell everything is in place for the shoulda test to pass, so why isn't it? Shoulda matchers are supposed to 'just work' with polymorphic associations. If I go into the console I can easily create treatments with complications. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try accessing the associations from console and do they work?

Comment: Have you run the migrations on your test database?

Comment: Yes I had tried the associations in the console, and yes they did work.

Comment: Erm, no I hadn't run the migration in my test database. Oops. All fine now. Write that as an answer and you get a nice shiny green tick.
(Walks away with head hung in shame).

Answer (score 3):

Run migrations on your test database!

...a mistake I have been caught by many times.

(the tick should got to Peter Alfvin)